# R - Looping over indexes from data frame

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to loop over a group of indexes from a data frame.
The data frame only has 1 column.

```
X  
1  
2  
3  
...
```

Considering the following variable **vars** which holds some indexes from the data frame:

```
   $1  
   [1]  1 28

   $2  
   [1] 29 61
```

I'm trying to loop over each of those and apply a function to each value in the data frame.
For example, I'm trying to loop over indexes 1 through 28, then apply a function, then loop over indexes 29 through 61, apply a different function and so on...
This is what I've tried.

```
z = list()
for (i in 1:length(vars)) { 
z[[i]] <- i
   for (j in vars[[i]][1]:vars[[i]][2]) {
   z[[i]][j] <- j
   }
}
```

Before applying the function to the data frame, and everything else. I would first just like to see if I'm getting the right indexes, but this is what I got.

```
[[1]]  
   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 

   [[2]]  
 [1]  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 29 30 31 32 33 34 35  
[36] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61
```

Which is not what I was expecting. 
The first list is fine, but can't tell what's happening with the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be better handled with `lapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100)
vars <- list(c(1,28), c(29,61))
str(lapply(vars, function(i) df$x[ i[1]:i[2] ]))
# List of 2
#  $ : int [1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ : int [1:33] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 ...
```

(The use of `str` was to shorten this display.)

If you want to apply some arbitrary function to each value within the range `1:28` (for example), do something else inside the function. For example:

```
func <- function(ab, x) { mean(x[ ab[1]:ab[2] ]); }
str(lapply(vars, func, df$x))
# List of 2
#  $ : num 14.5
#  $ : num 45
```

Here, `func` is a contrived arbitrary function that takes two arguments: a length-2 vector of index ends (i.e., `c(1,28)`), and the vector of values.

Notes about this example function:

1. I put the `ab` argument (indices) *first* intentionally, to facilitate the shorter notation within `lapply`. Note that `lapply(vars, func, df$x)` is expanded into `lapply(vars, function(a) func(a, df$x))`, so I think it's a little more readable above. If the arguments within `func` were reversed, you could not use the abbreviated format, instead requiring `lapply(vars, function(a) func(df$x, a))`.
2. There may be better ways to take the mean of that range; this is a trivial example to show how you could extend it.

Comment: Great! Just one thing. How can I apply a different function to each range? Say I want to take the mean to the first range (1:28) but the sum for the second range (29,61).

Comment: ([Scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep).) I suggest you change `vars` to be `data.frame`, something like `data.frame(ind1 = c(1,19), ind2 = c(28, 61), func = c(mean, sd))`, and iterate over each row.

Comment: You might also do `vars <- list( list(mean, 1, 28), list(sd, 29, 61) )`, and your internal use could be `function(z) z[[1]](df$x[z[[2]]:z[[3]]])`, though the brackets are starting to make me dizzy ...